# Гравитация на нативном JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как организовать гравитацию на js , то есть объект прыгает и приземляется на землю.

Comment: смещение объекта по таймауту на пиксель вниз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Ball(x, y, r, dx, dy) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;

  this.update = function() {
    // Bounce off the edges
    if (this.x - this.r + this.dx < 0 ||
        this.x + this.r + this.dx > w) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y - this.r + this.dy < 0 ||
        this.y + this.r + this.dy > h) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
    } else {
      // Our only acceleration is gravity
      this.dy += gravity;
    }
    
    this.x = this.x + this.dx;
    this.y = this.y + this.dy;
    
    this.stroke();
  };
  
  this.stroke = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r,
                 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.stroke();
  };
}

var gravity = 0.05;
var timeStep = 25; // In milliseconds
var w = c.canvas.width;
var h = c.canvas.height;
var cmTID;

function updateAll() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i = i + 1) {
    balls[i].update();
  }
  clearTimeout(cmTID);
  cmTID = setTimeout(updateAll, timeStep);
}

// Create the balls
var balls = [];
var r = 40;
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i = i + 1) {
  var x = Math.random() * (w - r * 2) + r;
  var y = Math.random() * (h - r * 2) + r;
  var dx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  var dy = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  
  balls.push(new Ball(x, y, r, dx, dy));
}
// Do the first update
updateAll();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="180"></canvas>
```

Код взят [отсюда](http://www.crunchzilla.com/code-maven) (ближе к концу примеры Acceleration, Velocity and Physics).

Используется `random`, поэтому иногда мячик скачет слабо. Тогда запустите код ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример на чистом js:

```js
let requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
let width = 100
let height = 120
let player = {
  x: width / 2,
  y: height - 5,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  speed: 3,
  velX: 0,
  velY: 0,
  jumping: false
}
let keys = []
let friction = 0.8
let gravity = 0.2

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

function update () {
  // проверка клавиш
  if (keys['ArrowUp'] || keys[' ']) { // ' ' значит пробел
    if (!player.jumping) {
      player.jumping = true
      player.velY = -player.speed * 2
    }
  }
  if (keys['ArrowRight']) {
    if (player.velX < player.speed) {
      player.velX++
    }
  }
  if (keys['ArrowLeft']) {
    if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
      player.velX--
    }
  }

  player.velX *= friction

  player.velY += gravity

  player.x += player.velX
  player.y += player.velY

  if (player.x >= width - player.width) {
    player.x = width - player.width
  } else if (player.x <= 0) {
    player.x = 0
  }

  if (player.y >= height - player.height) {
    player.y = height - player.height
    player.jumping = false
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)

  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  keys[event.key] = true
})

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  keys[event.key] = false
})

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  update()
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Если хотите делать 2d игру то очень советую использовать какой-то движок иначе будет очень тяжело.

Когда-то делал платформер на очень крутой либе для 2d физики: [Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/index.html)

```js
// алиасы модулей
const { Engine, Render, World, Bodies, Body, Runner, Events, Query } = Matter;
const { applyForce } = Body;
const keyboard = {};

// создает движок
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const engine = Engine.create();
const runner = Matter.Runner.create();
let ticks = 0;
let firstTick = true;

Runner.start(runner, engine);

// создает визуализатор
const render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine
});

// создать объекты(x, y, sizeX, sizeY)
const boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
const boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
const ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 1200, 60, { isStatic: true });
const platform = Bodies.rectangle(350, 450, 200, 60, { isStatic: true })
const platform2 = Bodies.rectangle(100, 350, 200, 60, { isStatic: true })
const surfaces = [
  ground,
  platform,
  platform2,
  boxB,
];

// добавить все тела в мир
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, ...surfaces]);

Events.on(runner, 'tick', (event) => {
  Render.lookAt(render, boxA, {x: 500, y: 500});
  const { delta } = event.source;
  if(ticks === 0 || ticks === 1) {
    firstTick = false;
  }
  const onGround = isOnSurface(boxA);
  const jumpSpeed = 20; // скорость прыжка
  const seconds = delta / 1000;
  const bottom = getBottom(boxA);
  const speed = 0.8 * (onGround ? 1 : 0.25); // скорость героя
  Body.setAngle(boxA, 0);
  
  /* УПРАВЛЕНИЕ */
  applyForce(boxA, bottom, {
    x: key('ArrowRight') * speed * seconds,
    y: 0
  });

  applyForce(boxA, bottom, {
    x: key('ArrowLeft') * speed * seconds * -1,
    y: 0
  });
  
  // только если на земле
  if(onGround) {
    applyForce(boxA, bottom, {
      x: 0,
      y: jumpSpeed * key('ArrowUp') * seconds * -1
    });
  }
  
  ticks++;
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  // console.log(event.key);
  keyboard[event.key] = 1;
  event.preventDefault();
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  keyboard[event.key] = 0;
});

// возвращает 1 если нажал на кнопку
function key(c) {
  return keyboard[c] || 0;
}

function getBottom(body) {
  const { min, max } = body.bounds;

  return {
    x: min.x + ((max.x - min.x) / 2),
    y: max.y
  };
}

function getBottomRight(body) {
  const { min, max } = body.bounds;

  return {
    x: min.x + (max.x - min.x),
    y: max.y
  };
}

function getBottomLeft(body) {
  const { min, max } = body.bounds;

  return {
    x: min.x,
    y: max.y
  };
}

function isOnSurface(body, floors=surfaces) {
  const bottomLeft = getBottomLeft(body);
  const bottomCenter = getBottom(body);
  const bottomRight = getBottomRight(body);

  return (
    Query.ray(floors, bottomLeft, {x: bottomLeft.x, y: bottomLeft.y + 1}).length ||
    Query.ray(floors, bottomCenter, {x: bottomCenter.x, y: bottomCenter.y + 1}).length ||
    Query.ray(floors, bottomRight, {x: bottomRight.x, y: bottomRight.y + 1}).length
  );
}

// запустить движок
Engine.run(engine);

// запустить визуализатор
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример, в нем в консоль кидает цифры у вас должно быть смещение на интервал. Не знаю кто дизлайкнул, кинул пример. При нажатии кнопки мышки будет лететь вверх.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIAAAAAA3pn/ZiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhA+hkcuO4lmNVindo7qyrIXiGBYAOw==';

var i = 0;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 500);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, i);
  i = i + 0.1;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();

// Нажимаем кнопкой мышки
document.addEventListener("mousedown", moveUp);

function moveUp() {
  i -= 3;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="500"></canvas>
```