# Мяч со временем теряет скорость

Tags: c++, математика

Есть мяч, который падает. Упав на землю, он отталкивается, но проблема в том, что после каждого отталкивания он поднимается на высоту меньше, чем в предыдущий раз. И так он до тех пор, пока его скорость не станет нулевой практически.
Вот код:

```
deltaTime = 1/60.f;
dy = dy + 100 * deltaTime;
y = y + dy * deltaTime;
if(y > 250){
  y = 250;
  dy = -dy;
}
```

Собственно, как сделать, чтобы мяч отталкивался бесконечно раз и поднимался все время на ту высоту, с которой начал падать?

Comment: Просто не пытаться считать численно то, что решается аналитически, и использовать аналитическую формулу, а не пытаться [даже немодифицированным] Эйлером с большим шагом решать нечто второго порядка...

Comment: Запишите позиции мяча при первом падении в табличку, затем повторяйте.

Comment: Может, будет полезно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/887367/184217

Comment: Очень интересная (и грустная) история про мячик. Но где код? В том коде, что вы привели, нет никакого "каждого отталкивания" и "предыдущего раза". Приводите реальный код, а не какой-то левый огрызок.

Answer (score 1):

Вы теряете расстояние при отскоке мяча, поэтому мяч и падает ниже. Вот как-то так должно быть:

```
deltaTime = 1/60.f;
dy = dy + 100 * deltaTime;
y = y + dy * deltaTime;
if(y > 250){
  y = 250-(y-250);
  dy = -dy;
}
```

Comment: Теперь мяч будет прыгать все выше и выше. Потому что после удара о поверхность до конца кванта времени интегрирования - мяч теряет скорость, а у вас как-бы наращивает.

Comment: Приведенный пример работает и работает корректно. Мяч корректно отскакивает до точки падения с небольшой +- погрешностью. Поведение при нефиксированном deltaTime или deltaTime>1 я не берусь предсказать, скорее всего мяч нужно будет принудительно ограничивать в точке начала падения, но это уже за пределами вопроса

Comment: ради интереса сделал тест вышеприведенного кода, при начальном значении dy=0 и y=0 после 1000000000 итераций мяч обратно допрыгивает до y=-5.30256e-08. По-моему, вполне приемлемая точность ;)